# Duplicate files in DerivedData folder using CoreData generator

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to generate NSManagedModels from my datamodel. Generation works but after I got many errors :

> error: filename "Station+CoreDataProperties.swift" used twice:
>   '/Users/Me/MyApp/Models/CoreData/Station+CoreDataProperties.swift' and
>   '/Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gwacspwrsnabomertjnqfbuhjvwc/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/Station+CoreDataProperties.swift'
>   :0: note: filenames are used to distinguish private
>   declarations with the same name

I try clean build folder and derivedData directory hard delete. I'm using Xcode 8 BETA maybe it's a bug ?

Comment: Try deleting derived data, Xcode -> File -> Project Settings.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese Lit I said in my post hard delete doesn't works! Thanks

Comment: Check your project directory double check that ```Station+CoreDataProperties.swift``` does not exists two times.

Comment: Are you using `cocoapods`? If you are, you have to specify `use_frameworks!` in your `podfile` and build it again.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese This file exists in my project directory and in DerivedData

Comment: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @TomHarrington Done! This "bug" is not fixed with BETA 2 :-( Roll back to XCode 7 and Swift 2.2 solve the issue

Comment: @Ludovic That is not an option; I started the project from an Xcode 8/Swift 3 template (Master Detail + CoreData).

Comment: @NicolasMiari what ?

Comment: Can't roll back to Xcode 7.3.1/Swift 2.2

Comment: @NicolasMiari yeah, Xcode 8 is stable. My post was with Xcode 8 beta and 7 stable

Comment: A change to the value of the `codegen` property may not "stick" if it's not accompanied with a change to the entity (e.g. rename an attribute).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I get this in Xcode 8.1
For me following steps solved the issue. Please note that order matters.

1) Create entity in Core Data model.

2) Under class section, make settings as on following image.

Module: Current Product Name

Codegen: Manual/None

3) Generate your NSManagedObject subclass.

[image]

Comment: For others, if your Core Data model is in an embedded framework, you need to set `Module` to `Global` otherwise you'll end up with two versions of your subclasses being compiled (the automatically generated ones by Xcode, and the ones you defined). _When you make this change, make sure you recreate your subclasses as well!_ If you dont, you'll end up with errors.

Comment: Terrific. Saved time.

Answer (score 11):

This post greatly helped me solve this problem myself. Personally I look at this as an Xcode bug. Bug or not this is a huge chicken and egg situation.

I ran into this by:

1. Created a new Project using Core Data
2. Generated my `NSManagedObject` subclass+extension (while `codegen: ClassDefinition`)
3. I accidentally saved the generated classes in the Wrong folder
4. I deleted the generated files
5. Re-generated in folder I wanted
6. - Xcode `used twice` errors

As others have posted I kept cleaning my build (and `clean build folder`) but that never fixed the build issue.

I finally figured out if you originally created your `NSManagedObject` generated classes with `codegen: ClassDefinition`, as I did without knowing then you are locked in for the chicken and egg issue.

I then deleted the auto generated classes *thinking* I had to re-generate, so I did. Once re-generated I would get the `used twice` build error again. I manually went into the `../DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/..` and deleted the *duplicates*. Again, I re-generated thinking I'd only have 1 copy (in my project) but I was wrong. If `codegen: ClassDefinition` was originally set then Xcode will keep creating the `auto-generated` classes+extensions and put them in the buried folder `../DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/..`. I repeated this chicken and egg a few times before catching on.

I later realized you do indeed need to mark `codegen: Manual/None` however to get things back in sync you need to delete the auto-generated files in `../DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/..` and in your project if you have any there still.

Be careful setting `codegen: Manual/None`, for me it was bit tricky because `codegen: Manual/None` wouldn't *stick*. I had to click back and forth between entities multiple times to double/triple check each entity was set to `codegen: Manual/None`. *Then* auto generate the files. At this point your only copy of the auto generated files should be in your project and not in `../DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/..`.

Last, I think this is a bug because if you specify `codegen: Manual/None` I don't expect Xcode to auto generate files at all, yet it does and puts them in your project. More confusing if your setting is `codegen: ClassDefinition`, who the heck knows Xcode will put the files in a buried directory yet it is available for use in your project. My beef with this is the auto generated files aren't source controlled and if I change computer I have to know to auto-generate them on the new station.

Hope this helps someone else!

Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

This is indeed not a bug. As @Morrowless suggests both class definition and properties extension are created.  If this is not wanted, select **Manual/None** under Codegen **before** generating the code. If the code is already generated, just delete them, and try `Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass...`  again from the menu (after setting Manual/None).

Note, in the picture below, the Class Name 'Contact' is specific to my project. You will see your entity name instead.

[image]

Comment: Please check Apple Bug Reporter and read my post again! Apple Solved this issue with 8.1.

Comment: Just downloaded 8.1. Added a TestEntity to my model and added two attributes, String and Date, and created NSManagedObjectSubclass from the menu. Not to my surprise, I still get the error, as this was not a bug in the first place. My solution above worked and fixed the problem. You need to set the `Module` to `Current Product Module` and `Codegen` to `Manual/None`.

Comment: Manual was set in my project, update to 8.1 solved my issue. Look at bug tracker. But you right if the user doesn't set manual mode it"s not a bug :)

Answer (score 5):

If you generated CoreData subclasses with `codegen: ClassDefinition` your basically screwed. The only way to fix it is to:

1. Delete your CoreData subclasses.
2. Delete your derived data folder.
3. Clean your project (CMD+K).
4. Generate new CoreData subclasses, this time select `Codegen: Manual/None` and `Module: Current Product Module`

Comment: He isn't screwed. Deleting `DerivedData`, changing the 'Codegen' property on each entity to `Manual/None`, then cleaning and building will do the trick. No need to delete and re-create the CoreData subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not a bug.** Codegen generates these files in the DerivedData folder, so you don't need to create them again in your project, hence the compile error.

From Xcode 8.0 Release notes:

> Xcode automatically generates classes or class extensions for the entities and properties in a Core Data data model. Automatic code generation is enabled and disabled on an entity by entity basis, and is enabled for all entities in new models that use the Xcode 8 file format. This feature is available for any data model that has been upgraded to the Xcode 8 format. You specify whether Xcode generates Swift or Objective-C code for a data model using the data model’s file inspector.
>
> When automatic code generation is enabled for an entity, Xcode creates
>   either a class or class extension for the entity as specified in the
>   entity's inspector: the specified class name is used and the sources
>   are placed in the project’s Derived Data. For both Swift and
>   Objective-C, these classes are directly usable from the project’s
>   code. For Objective-C, an additional header file is created for all
>   generated entities in your model. The header file name conforms to the
>   naming convention “DataModelName+CoreDataModel.h”.

**However**, if you selected Category/Extension under the codegen pulldown menu in the data model inspector (because you want to add logic to your model): **codegen will wrongly generate both the class definition and properties extension**.

The solution is to simply delete the properties extension (**ClassName**+CoreDataProperties.swift). Your project should now compile.

Comment: Please check Apple Bug Reporter and read my post again! Apple Solved this issue with 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

After following the guidance from oyalhi and Vladimir Shutyuk, (deleting the `NSManagedObject` files, changing the entity `codegen` to `Manual/None`), I had to restart Xcode to allow it to index again before I could re-generate the `NSManagedObject` files and get a successful compile.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness..:

I just ran into the same error, but none of the proposed solutions worked. What puzzled me was that even switching from automated code generation to manual for the one (as I thought) problematic entity didn't do anything.

Finally, I figured out that I had several entities with the same *name*, but they all shared the same *classname*. The reason for this was that I copy&pasted one entity several times to save me some work, because they also have a few attributes in common.

Turns out XCode renames the duplicates by adding 1, 2,... to the entity name, but leaves the class name as before. And since now entity name and class name are "unrelated", renaming the entity won't change the class name either.

Hope it helps someone - I have also filed a bug report for this.