# CoreData codegen toolchain error with Xcode 8.1

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift3, xcode8

When generating code for my entity TrackPoint, I get compiler error

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Xcode also complains that the `TrackPoint+CoreDataClass.swift` and `TrackPoint+CoreDataProperties.swift` filenames are used twice, once in the project location and once in derived data. Deleting derived data had no effect.

Ideas how to fix the problem are welcome.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366329/filenames-are-used-to-distinguish-private-declarations-of-the-same-name-error or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190360/duplicate-files-in-deriveddata-folder-using-coredata-generator?

Comment: Thanks Martin, this resolves the issue