# CoreData/Entity error does not disappear even though there is no more entity

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I am facing a `CoreData` related issue, and keep getting this error message:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

More precisely, before the message above is displayed, I can see these details:

```
<unknown>:0: error: filename "NiceEntity+CoreDataProperties.swift" used twice: '../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NiceApp-bactemnueukiynkkjghppujjxzyht/Build/Intermediates/NiceApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NiceApp.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/BWP/NiceEntity+CoreDataProperties.swift' and '../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NiceApp-bactemnueukiynkkjghppujjxzyht/Build/Intermediates/NiceApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NiceApp.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/BWP/NiceEntity+CoreDataProperties.swift'
<unknown>:0: note: filenames are used to distinguish private declarations with the same name
```

I know I made some wrong manipulations when first setting up the entity NiceEntity, but I have removed everything that I could see related to this entity. That is I removed the entity NiceEntity from the data model and I erased the DerivedData/NiceApp-bactemnueukiynkkjghppujjxzyht folder. And yet the error has not disappeared.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve that?

In case this may be useful, I am using Xcode Version 8.3.2.

Comment: How you delete derived folder is also important sometimes. You must open the derived data folder and then quit the xcode before deleting the folder.

Comment: I just tried again by deleting the DerivedData/NiceApp-bactemnueukiynkkjghppujjxzyht folder (from the terminal), after quitting Xcode, but it doesn't change anything. The problem stays.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion you "**Reset Content and Settings**" again in the simulator to make sure you have a clean foundation again.
Also **Clean Build Folder**.

Hope it helps, 
Cheers glnj

Comment: What do you mean by "Reset Content and Settings" again in the simulator? I am not using the simulator. I am only trying to compile and build.
And I almost always  Clean Build Folder. This still doesn't work.

Comment: Check this post should help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190360/duplicate-files-in-deriveddata-folder-using-coredata-generator

Cheers nj
PS Reset Content and Settings option is for simulator we normally reset it if we change any Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me at the end.

I removed all the entities that I had added recently, that is those in some ways related to my issue. I then rebuilt them one by one (I was lucky that there were not too many), and the problem magically disappeared. Who knows what dirty things I had been doing before?